# AutoHotKey: Can I assign shift + number the way so it work like usual

Tags: numbers, autohotkey, shift

A few days ago my Coca Cola bottle decided to accidently hit my keyboard. Now after I dried it off it's working all fine. However, there is a strange problem.

The SHIFT key is working perfectly as all the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and 0, however, when I try to use the standard windows combination for

```
Shift+1 
shift+2 
shift+3
```

It doesn't work. Again my Shift key and the numbers are working fine, but hitted together they do nothing. Then I found the AutoHotKey program and I was thinking to assign

```
Shift+1 = ! 
Shift+2 = @ 
Shift+3 = # 
Shift+4 = $ 
Shift+5 = % 
Shift+6 = ^ 
Shift+7 = & 
Shift+8 = * 
Shift+9 = ( 
Shift+0 = )
```

As it is meant to be

All other shift + key combinations are working fine
like shift + r = R

I have browsed the tutorial, however, not being a programmer I understood close to nothing.
Anyone can help me here?

My keyboard is a gaming Cyborg keyboard that shine in different colors and I have paid €80 for it, so I really wish to keep on using it...

Big thanks, guys!!!

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would have used +Nr, but to be sure I used a Send, {Sign} method here. Also,  since you define the hotkey to be the sane as the output, you need a $ sign in front of every hotkey to prevent each key from looping it self.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
AppName=KeyMod
Menu, Tray, Tip, %AppName%
Menu, Tray, Icon , Shell32.dll, 45, 1
TrayTip, %AppName%, Started, 1
SoundBeep, 300, 150
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
$+1::Send, {!}
$+2::Send, {@}
$+3::Send, {#}
$+4::Send, {$}
$+5::Send, {`%}
$+6::Send, {^}
$+7::Send, {&}
$+8::Send, {*}
$+9::Send, {(}
$+0::Send, {)}
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert,

Seems like the code is working fine, as I tried to change one of the lines and put a letter instead of a character and it working with my other keyboard.

However, on my cyborg keyboard it's not working. Seems like the Cola have broken it so the shift + NR doesnt work at all

Thanks anyway, your post was helpfull!

Comment: Change the + signs to ^ for Control or ! for Alt or # for Win. So #3::Send, {#}  will trigger when you press [Win]+3  or !3::Send, {#} will trigger when you press [Alt]+3